# Doesn't recoil trigger the re-renders of parent elements ahead the re-renders of their children?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, recoiljs

Please take a look at the following code.

```js
const fooState = atom<string | null>({ key: 'foo', default: "Hello" });

const A = () => {
  const foo = useRecoilValue(fooState);

  if(foo === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return <B />
}

const B = () => {
  const foo = useRecoilValue(fooState);
  
  if(foo === null) {
    throw new Error('This can\'t happen.');
  }

  // ...  
}
```

As you can see, the value of `foo` is nullable and the nullability determines whether to render `B` as a child of `A`. `fooState` is set to "Hello" by default, so at the first time `B` would be rendered.
Now let's consider that `fooState` gets set to `null`. Then the usages of  `useRecoilValue(fooState)` should trigger a re-rendering of its component. So `A` and `B` will be re-rendered.

At this time, `A` needs to be rendered first preventing the app from crash. If not, the line `throw new Error('This can\'t happen.')` in `B` would be executed.
I tested the code above and it worked well as I intended.

> However, it seems it doesn't  always work in this way.
>
> I'm using React Native and React Navigation. I found that recoil
> didn't trigger re-rendering as I expected with React Navigation's
> component. I guess that React Navigation can do unordinary things in
> mounting its component and they could make problems with recoil.
> Before investigating this speculation, I want to sure about the
> recoil's behavior in ordinary cases.

Is it guaranteed that the re-rendering triggered by the updates of atoms occurs in the parent components first? If not, the logic in the example is not acceptable with Recoil, while it is totally acceptable with React Context.
In which order does Recoil triggers re-rendering when its atoms get updated?